# Get most distant number php

Tags: php, distance

i want to have the most distant number but i can only find the function max in php manuals.

Example:

```
$1 = -0.25%
$2 =  0.45%
$3 = -1.25%
$4 =  1.15%
```

I want the $3 number because it has the most distant from 0...

when you use the max function i get $4 but that is not what i want, does anyone have a good solution for this or do i have to make a function ?

I dont know what to write but i get the error that its not good enough what i wrote here

```
$test1 = "-0.25%";
$test2 =  "0.45%";
$test3 = "-1.25%";
$test4 =  "1.15%";

$arrayprices = array($test1, $test2, $test3, $test4);

$min = min($arrayprices);
$max = max($arrayprices);

$result = abs($min) > abs($max) ? $min : $max;
echo $result;
```

answer: 1.15% but it should be -1.25

Comment: Your variable names are wrong...

Comment: It was an example @Leonardo, im sure!

Comment: Get the min and max, and then compare their absolute values. The result you want is the one with the largest abs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$array = array(-0.25, 0.45, -1.25, 1.15);
$min = min($array);
$max = max($array);
$result = abs($min) > abs($max) ? $min : $max;
echo $result;
```

Comment: i get 0 as result when i echo it, maybe because of the abs ?

Comment: @MichaelAngelo can you please show the exact code you just used.

Comment: It works for me. I just updated the answer with my full code.

Comment: @MichaelAngelo it works perfectly for me as well, check your code.

Comment: Numbers can't have special characters like `%` in them.

Comment: When you use non-numeric strings, `min` and `max` do lexicographic comparisons instead of numeric comparisons.

Comment: i removed the % with substring now it works great! thanks guys

Comment: wait i have a problem it does not work when the numbers are with , instead of .

Comment: PHP only understands `.` as the decimal point. You need to reformat them if you're using a different format.

Answer (score 3):

before using max on all your values!

```
abs($yourvaluehere)
```

Comment: if you do this to all your values, you'll lose the negative sign when you try to return the result.

Comment: @Barmar, No, that would only happen if he assigned them to the exact same variable.

Comment: Then he has to somehow keep track of which values in the updated list correspond to the original list. It would help if you showed the actual code you're suggesting that does this. This minimalist answer is likely to be confusing to someone who couldn't figure it out himself.

Comment: i get 0 when i use abs

Comment: `$A = 1.1255; echo abs($A);` does not equal 0. Check your code.